# Auto Selecting the next Input field and going Back

Tags: javascript, jquery

Once inputed, a user can't go back to change their input.

```js
$("form").on("keyup change paste", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var a = $(this).find("input[type='text'].a");
  var b = $(this).find("input[type='text'].b");
  var c = $(this).find("input[type='text'].c");
  var d = $(this).find("input[type='text'].d");
  var e = $(this).find("input[type='text'].e");
  var f = $(this).find("input[type='text'].f");

  a.val(a.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));
  b.val(b.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));
  c.val(c.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));
  d.val(d.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));
  e.val(e.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));
  f.val(f.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));

  if (a.val().length == a.attr('maxlength')) {
    a.next("input").focus();
  }
  if (b.val().length == a.attr('maxlength')) {
    b.next("input").focus();
  }
  if (c.val().length == a.attr('maxlength')) {
    c.next().next("input").focus();
  }
  if (d.val().length == a.attr('maxlength')) {
    d.next("input").focus();
  }
  if (e.val().length == a.attr('maxlength')) {
    e.next("input").focus();
  }
  if (f.val().length == a.attr('maxlength')) {
    f.next("input").focus();
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="code" action="*" method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" name="code" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" class="a">
  <input type="text" name="code" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" class="b">
  <input type="text" name="code" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" class="c">
  <span>—</span>
  <input type="text" name="code" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" class="d">
  <input type="text" name="code" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" class="e">
  <input type="text" name="code" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" class="f last">
</form>
```

How can that be done?

And is there a more elegant approach to mine above?

---

**Live: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bgqenpc/2/)**

Comment: To be sure I understand it well, you want to disallow the user to change a number it inserted ?

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT Once you're at the end, and you want to erase some number back. Currently you'd have to go into each field and edit them that way.

Comment: Doesn't feel like a very user-friendly way to go about things, but if you really want to stop users from editing a filled input field, just bind the `focus` event to the input field. In the callback, if the input's `value` property evaluates to truthy, you forcibly invoke the `blur()` method.

Comment: @Terry Well no it's not. Because the input cannot be easily erased currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you find yourself finding very repetitious code, always think LOOP.

The below will allow the user to edit their values. It also greatly reduces your code.

```
$('form').on('input', e => {
    var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
    letters.forEach(letter => {
        let field = $(e.target);
        field.val(field.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
        if(field.val().length == field.attr('maxlength')) { field.nextAll('input').first().focus(); }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbyxcm1p/1).

Notes:

- Listen for the input event; it has the advantage of covering all the events you were listening for, and, crucially, fires *after* keypress (meaning you can be sure of grabbing the latest, complete value from the field)
- avoid repetitious code; the loop allows us to write the business logic once rather than repeatedly
- there is no need to prevent the event's default action
- by using `nextAll('input').first()`, we can be sure of getting the next `input`, whether it's the next sibling or, as is the case with the third input, separated by another type of element

Comment: Works great on initial input. However if a user wanted to change their input by erasing from field `f` towards field `a`, can that be done?

Comment: "erasing from field f towards field a" - not sure what you mean

Comment: So I've entered 123-123. I am now at `input.f`. I erase `input.f`. And the focus should jump back to `input.e`.

Comment: OK, well that's different from your current question. And I can't see any UI sense in why that should happen, but that's just my opinion. Why not have a go yourself.

Comment: Please create a stackoverflow snippet instead of a Fiddle, it's way easier to try out

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT - this makes sense only if you include the HTML also, which my answer doesn't. The question was about JS, and without the HTML the JS has no demo'ability.

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to focus next, and loop when arriving at the last one. Replace the number in case of a new entry.

```js
// init the html
const nbInput = 6;

let html = '';

for (let i = 0; i < nbInput; i += 1) {
  html += `<input type="text" name="code" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" number="${i}">`;
}

$('form').html(html);

$('form input').on('keypress', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // Ignore bad values
  if (/^[^0-9]$/g.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) {
    return;
  }

  // Replace the actual value with the keypressed one
  $(this).val(String.fromCharCode(e.which));

  // Reset & focus next
  if ($(this).val() !== '' && Number($(this).attr('number')) < (nbInput - 1)) {
    $(`input[number=${Number($(this).attr('number')) + 1}]`).focus();
  } else {
    // Focus the first item when we finished
    $('input[number="0"]').focus();
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="code" action="*" method="post" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the inputs on focus would do it. (I don't use jQuery much, so apologies if I have any incorrect syntax.)

```
$("form").focus(function() {

    var a = $(this).find("input[type='text'].a")
    var b = $(this).find("input[type='text'].b") // ...etc  

    a.val("");
    b.val(""); // ...etc
});
```

That said, Utkanos is 100% correct that a loop is the right way to handle both issues (auto-advancing and allowing edits).